# I need an explanation on why this line of code is preventing my progress loader from displaying and how to fix it

Tags: flutter

I need an explanation on why this line of code is preventing my progress loader from displaying and how to fix it.

This is the particular line "child: ModalBarrier(dismissible: false, color: color"
And if the line is removed, it won't display the circular loader animation properly
Below is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProgressHUD extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final bool inAsyncCall;
  final double opacity;
  final Color color;
  final Animation<Color> valueColor;

  ProgressHUD({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.inAsyncCall,
    this.opacity = 0.3,
    this.color = Colors.grey,
    this.valueColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> widgetList = new List<Widget>();
    widgetList.add(child);
    if (inAsyncCall) {
      final modal = new Stack(
        children: [
          new Opacity(
            opacity: opacity,
            child: ModalBarrier(dismissible: false, color: color),
          ),
          new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator()),
        ],
      );
      widgetList.add(modal);
    }
    return Stack(
      children: widgetList,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I later did

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> widgetList = <Widget>[];
    widgetList.add(child);
    if (inAsyncCall) {
      final modal = SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Stack(
        children: [
          Opacity(
            opacity: opacity,
            child: const ModalBarrier(dismissible: false, color: Palette.backgroundColor,),
          ),
          const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Palette.backgroundColor))),
        ]
      )
      );
      widgetList.add(modal);
    }
    return Stack(
      children: widgetList,
    );
  }
```